# AceEdit collapsing dynamically

Tags: ace-editor

I wish my AceEdit displaying all the uppermost classes and functions collapsed when the source code is loaded (or a "collapse all" button was pressed).

I think i missed somewhat, shouldn't it be easy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently ace only provides options to [`foldAll`](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.1.6/lib/ace/commands/default_commands.js#L123) and [`foldOther`](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.1.6/lib/ace/commands/default_commands.js#L127)

if foldAll hides too much you can use

```
editor.session.foldAll();
editor.session.unfold([...Array of ranges to not hide]);
```

If that doesn't work for you and you think this is a common functionality in other editors you can create an issue [here](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/new)